# Bindable must be on a member in an Observable class

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I'm new in data binding , this is my code but I get this error on building

```
class DatabindingViewModel :ViewModel() {

val currentFruitName:LiveData<String>
    get() = FakeRepository.currentName

fun changeNameOnClick()=FakeRepository.changeRandomFoodName()

//two way LiveData
@Bindable
val editTextContext= MutableLiveData<String>()

private val _displayEditTexfContent=MutableLiveData<String>()
val displayEditTexfContent:LiveData<String>
    get()=_displayEditTexfContent

fun onDisplayEtText(){
    _displayEditTexfContent.value=editTextContext.value
}
```

this is my xml layout code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="binding"
            type="ir.persiandesigners.myapplication.databinding.viewmodel.DatabindingViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:text="@{binding.currentFruitName}"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:onClick="@{()->binding.changeNameOnClick()}"
            android:text="Get Random  Name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="@={binding.editTextContext}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:onClick="@{()->binding.onDisplayEtText()}"
            android:text="Change Display Text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

this is the code I've in the activity:

```
val viweModel= ViewModelProviders.of(this)
            .get(DatabindingViewModel::class.java)

    DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActvitiyDatadindingBinding>(
            this,R.layout.actvitiy_datadinding)
            .apply {
                this.setLifecycleOwner( this@DataBindingAct)
                this.binding=viweModel
            }

    viweModel.editTextContext.observe(this, Observer{
        Toast.makeText(this@DataBindingAct,it ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    })
```

when I want to build the project and run it , I get this error :

```
e: error: Bindable must be on a member in an Observable class. DatabindingViewModel is not Observable
```

could you help me ?

I've tried to clean the project , rebuild and so on but there is an error in my code that I couldn't find

could you help me ?

Comment: Quick googling the error "Bindable must be on a member in an Observable class" brought me multiple results, including this post that may be help you.  https://www.javatips.net/api/android.databinding.bindable

Comment: @fluidguid I've googled but couldnt  solve my problem

Comment: I think the error explains it all. Your `ViewModel` should implement `Observable`, like `BaseObservable`. See [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#two-way-custom-attrs)

Answer (score 25):

Just remove @Bindable annotation from Viewmodel and your code will run successfully and error will be resolved.

The **@Bindable** annotation should only be applied when you are accessing getter method while extending **BaseObservable** class which itself implements Observable interface for observing data.

> Here LiveData itself is an observable data holder class

So, you don't need to implement @Bindable and BaseObservable class for observing data.

**docs**: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/Bindable

I hope things are clear now.

Comment: It works. Can you please explain what it is not required anymore? Doc ref please?

Comment: Explain please?

Answer (score 6):

You have to implement Observable Interface and add its methods

here is mine,

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel(), Observable { 

private val callbacks: PropertyChangeRegistry by lazy { PropertyChangeRegistry()}

    override fun removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback: Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback?) {
        callbacks.add(callback)
    }

    override fun addOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback: Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback?) {
        callbacks.remove(callback)
    }
}// class ends here
```

Answer (score -1):

Do the following step-by-step:

- **Clean Project**
- **Rebuild Project**
- **Invalidate Caches / Restart**

Trust me, it should work. I know the solution is simple but I also wasted my 3 hours 'cuz of this. Follow these 3 steps and you should be good to go.